# Drupal 8 preprocess page

Tags: twig, drupal-8, preprocessor

I'm new in Drupal 8 & I have an issue.
I need to display a CCK field (custom field) in my theme page `page-front.html.twig`.

As I understand it's impossible to display node variables in a non-node page, so I start to do a preprocess hook.

My preprocess looks like this:

**mythemename.theme**

```
<?php

function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $node = $vars['node'];
    if ($node->isset('field_numero_cin') {
      $field_cin = $node->get('field_numero_cin');
      $vars['field_cin'] = $field_image->value();
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I'm debugging (kint) my variable in `page-front.html.twig` is `NULL`.

Comment: I don't like me too comments. But, I don't want to duplicate the question. I am also facing the same issue. You fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

Humm...

- Are you entering the preprocess ? ( add a debug message before your
  first "`if`")
- You're trying to access `$field_image`'s value with `->value()`. Try
  with `->getValue()` or `->value`
- Stupid question but maybe worth-it : Have you tried clearing the cache ? It's needed after added a preprocess function.

Answer (score 0):

Your second if statement is is missing a close bracket, are you getting an error?`if ($node->isset('field_numero_cin')) {
      $field_cin = $node->get('field_numero_cin');
      $vars['field_cin'] = $field_image->value();
    }`